# Delete duplicated items across different tables in MariaDB / SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb, innodb

I have a Wordpress Database with two tables with this structure

Table 1 "location"

```
id, postID, address

1, 123, park ave
2, 234, washington ave
3, 345, wall st
4, 456, park ave
5, 567, wall st
```

Table 2 "posts"

```
postID, title
123, "Foxtown restaurant"
234, "Tony's pizza"
345, "Roxy"
456, "Foxtown restaurant"
567, "Roxy"
```

(edited to make clear what "titles" are)

I need to DELETE the duplicated rows/items based on the "address" in table 1.

I do not care about whether to keep the newest or oldest data, that's irrelevant as they are records created twice by accident.

So, I tried this:

```
DELETE S1 FROM location AS S1  
INNER JOIN location AS S2   
WHERE S1.id > S2.id AND S1.address = S2.address;
```

But this removes the duplicated records in "location" (perfect) but keeps the records in "posts", simply without any associated address.

I tried doing something similar with "posts"

```
DELETE S1 FROM posts AS S1  
INNER JOIN posts AS S2   
WHERE S1.id > S2.id AND S1.title = S2.title;
```

But I realized that I cannot use the "title" feature in "posts" since there are records with the same title but a different address in table 1 (so, actually non-duplicated records).

For example I can have in `location`

```
6, 999, Brickell ave
```

And in `posts`

```
999, "Roxy"
```

Which IS NOT a duplicate, since it's another Roxy in another location.

Ideas?

Comment: What role does the `posts` table play here, given that all 5 titles are distinct?

Comment: Imagine that "posts" are
123, "Foxtown restaurant",
234, "Tony's pizza",
345, "Roxy",
456, "Foxtown restaurant",
567, "Roxy"

Comment: The `location` table does not have a `title` column, or maybe it is not shown.

Comment: Yes, correct. the location table does not have a title. The postID is the element that links "location" with "posts".

So, in the end, you have "Foxtown restaurant" that is located at "park ave".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set up your foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
That way, whenever a row in the parent table is deleted, any related rows in the child table will be deleted automatically.

Here is an example of a way to alter a table in order to create a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE

```
ALTER TABLE child_table
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

In your casen it would be something like this

```
ALTER TABLE location 
  ADD CONSTRAINT postID 
  FOREIGN KEY (postID) 
  REFERENCES posts(postID) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides an `ON DELETE CASCADE` you can do a classical DELETE FROM multiple Tables

```
CREATE TABLE location
    (`id` int, `postID` int, `address` varchar(14))
;
    
INSERT INTO location
    (`id`, `postID`, `address`)
VALUES
    (1, 123, 'park ave'),
    (2, 234, 'washington ave'),
    (3, 345, 'wall st'),
    (4, 456, 'park ave'),
    (5, 567, 'wall st')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE posts
    (`postID` int, `title` varchar(20))
;
    
INSERT INTO posts
    (`postID`, `title`)
VALUES
    (123, 'Foxtown restaurant'),
    (234, 'Tony''s pizza'),
    (345, 'Roxy'),
    (456, 'Foxtown restaurant'),
    (567, 'Roxy')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
DELETE L1,P1 FROM location AS L1  
INNER JOIN location AS L2   ON L1.id > L2.id AND L1.address = L2.address
INNER JOIN posts as P1 ON P1.postID = L1.postID
```

```
SELECT * FROM location
```

| id | postID | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | park ave |
| 2 | 234 | washington ave |
| 3 | 345 | wall st |

```
SELECT * FROM posts
```

| postID | title |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Foxtown restaurant |
| 234 | Tony's pizza |
| 345 | Roxy |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dZKg9iQd)